# Find product id and producer id from database

Tags: mysql, database

I am new in SQL, and I have been trying to learn this on my own so that I can do some works later on. I am working on mySQL. I have been working on a product vs producer database for practice and I am stuck at some point of it. My tables are:

producer(producerid , produceraddress)

product(productid , productname)

cost(producerid , productid, price)

Now I want to find: 1. products produced by at least two different producers and 2. pairs of producers such that the first producer charges more for some product than the second producer.

I am totally lost. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

With these schemas you can't do it.

You need to do again your schemas and read about relations between tables.

For example if you have the Producer table with producer_id and producer_name and in your products table product_id and product_name you can't say I want to see this product that is made by this producer.

In your product table you must add a new field that could be producer_id and it will be a reference to the producer_id from producer table. With this you could retrieve from the database a product that it's made for the producer you are interested.